# word for more frequent than "frequent"

Tags: single-word-requests

I wanted to say that

> I'm a frequent restaurant visitor

in order to express my authority on the restaurant subject.

But *frequent* doesn't quite catch it: I visit a restaurant almost every other day. The first word that comes to mind after *frequent* is *often*, but you can't say

> I'm an often restaurant visitor

Another word that comes to mind is *obsessive*, but that has other connotations.

What word could I use instead of *frequent* without rewriting the sentence?

Comment: How about “I don’t cook”? You eat out 3–4 times a week.

Comment: ***Regular, usual, recurrent.***

Comment: ... very frequent.

Comment: I'm such a frequent visitor that they had to widen the door for me.

Comment: constant visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word that comes to mind to replace *frequent* here would be *avid*

> I'm an avid restaurant visitor

The word *avid* has a positive connotation as it refers to showing a keen or enthused interest in the subject matter (restaurants in this case), and holds the implication that you visit restaurants often, as it is an activity that you derive pleasure from.

> [Definition of Avid:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/avid) Having or showing a keen interest in or enthusiasm for something.

Comment: Having 'a keen interest in or enthusiasm for' restaurants does not by itself entail anything about how frequently one visits them. One can, for example, be very enthusiastic about dining in restaurants whenever one can afford it, but not do it very frequently, because one cannot afford it.

Answer (score 1):

**habitual**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/habitual)

**done or experienced regularly and repeatedly**

Better than obsessive and implies 'you know about eating out'!

Answer (score 1):

always

I forget what the other specific term is but I know it exists. Using "always" figuratively and not literally is a type of hyperbole:

As a figure of speech, it is usually not meant to be taken literally.
[Hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole)

> "He is always working."
>  "He always forgets things."

Nobody seriously takes these to mean "always" literally, as in working 24/7, or that he forgets absolutely everything as if some kind of anterograde amnesiac.

Your example:

> "I'm always eating out at restaurants."

Answer (score 0):

Here are three choices that might work for what you are looking for:

"persistently"
"constantly"
"regularly"

I hope you find one of those useful.

Comment: Welcome to the English Language & Usage stack exchange site! Your answer would benefit from linked references to support your claim (say an online dictionary).